# Provide custom Webform element with no user-facing options?

Tags: webforms, 9

Is there a way with Webform 6 to create custom element plugins that do not have any user-facing options?

For example, creating a select element that is usable in webforms, but its option list comes from a remote API - therefore does not need the editors to enter values in the UI?

Comment: [Webform remote selecŧ](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_remote_select) should do exactly what you ask in your example. It probably would be also a good starting point to develop other kind of "remote" elements.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I used a plugin with "Remote" as a base, but still got options. Did not see this though.